# Avoid auto generated namespace in Visual Studio. How to turn off automatic insertion of "using System;"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, intellisense

I am using VS Community 2017 Version 15.2

When I use the light-bulb suggestions, or manually press (Ctrl + .), it generates a method like this:

```
using System;
public void f() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I want it to be this way:

```
public void f() {
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Without the:

```
using System;
```

I looked through the settings and also online but could not find the option.

I want this because I like keeping my namespace clean. I don't want to manually delete the using statement every time I use this handy feature.

Comment: Your namespace is not affected by anything in `System`. `using` just makes names available in your local file. It makes no sense to deliberately avoid it unless you're planning on introducing names that collide with those in `System`, which would be a bad idea. C# is not C++; every argument that exists there for avoiding `using namespace` pretty much doesn't apply (or, at least, they simply don't outweigh the readability benefit).

Comment: Maybe you can open Tools > Code Snippets Manager, and finding the correct snippet that is used and modify it. I do not know the syntax for it though. [Check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5941d54(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info

Comment: if you put the `using system` at the very top of the program it isnt needed again anywhere else and its out of the way

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the opinion but your answer is not very useful. Even the fact that I get many more unnecessary code suggestions while typing when "using System" is enough for me to not want it.

Comment: @tupcuhamdi: it's a comment, not an answer. I often break the rule on not posting answers in comments, but this isn't one of those occasions. It's not my intent to give an actual answer to your question.

Comment: @tupcuhamdi, As far as I know, there has no such option in VS to turn off their default using statements when you create the C# projects. Maybe you can try to create project templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates, edit the project to remove those using statements and go to Project-Export Template to export, then choose this customized template when you create the new projects, or report your ideas to the VS Product Team in here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: I'm using Unity Engine, and there's collusion between certain classes in Unity and System, for example the "Random" class. So when using Unity, the namespace for certain classes should always be specified if you're also using System.

Comment: @blobkat You mean confusion? Collusion is when two things secretly work together. I assume that's actually the opposite of what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a  common behaviour, and Visual studio does not provide it. If you use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), you can set it manually.

Resharper -> Option

[image]

(in option window) Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style

[image]

Find *Reference qualification* and check *prefer fully qualified references*